# 'AdlsClient' does not contain a definition for 'CreateDocumentAsync'

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-lake

TARGET:
Create Console Application, which 1) Read json from Azure Data Lake Store 2) Store data to Cosmos DB as json.

PROBLEM:
I can read file (1), but cannot stores data to Cosmos. See error.

ERROR:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'AdlsClient' does not contain a definition for 'CreateDocumentAsync' and no extension method 'CreateDocumentAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'AdlsClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) CircleCustomActivityCosmosDB    C:\AzureCoding\CustomActivityCosmosDB\Program.cs

CODE:

```
private  async Task CreateDocumentsAsync()
        {
            string fileName = "/myjsonfile.json";

            // Obtain AAD token for ADLS 
            var creds = new ClientCredential(applicationId, clientSecret);
            var clientCreds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, creds).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            // Create ADLS client object
            AdlsClient client = AdlsClient.CreateClient(adlsAccountFQDN, clientCreds);

        String json = "";

            //Read file contents
            using (var readStream = new StreamReader(client.GetReadStream(fileName)))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = readStream.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Read file Line: " + line);
                    json += line;
                }
            }

            //Read file to json
            JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));

            //Storing json to CosmosDB
            Uri collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName);

            //ERROR HAPPENS HERE - 'AdlsClient' does not contain a definition for 'CreateDocumentAsync' and no extension method 'CreateDocumentAsync'  
        await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionUri, reader);

        }

   }
```

Comment: I do wonder, did you copy/paste the cosmos db part of the code from somewhere? I mean, wouldn't tell intellisense you otherwise that you have the wrong class or method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `CreateDocumentAsync` method defined for the class `AdlsClient`, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.datalake.store.adlsclient?view=azure-dotnet#Methods_)

You need a CosmosDB client to create the document there, I think you want to use [DocumentClient.CreateDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createdocumentasync?view=azure-dotnet) instead.

The `AdlsClient` class gives to methods to access the Azure Data Lake Store only, not the CosmosDB datastore. For that, you need the `DocumentClient` class, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient?view=azure-dotnet).

So summarized:

> TARGET: Create Console Application, which 1) Read json from Azure Data Lake Store 2) Store data to Cosmos DB as json.

for 1) you need AdlsClient (to access adls)

for 2) you need DocumentClient (to access cosmosdb)